Remove and change name of fields from a JSON payload in WSO2 API Manager
I have an API Manager 4.1.0 of WSO2, where I did an API expose from my backend where it delivers the following payload. I want to change some fields' names and remove others, as below.
{
  "institution": "Core - API Manager",
  "description": "Sistema de API Rest",
  "api_version": "tag_version",
  "user_ip": "10.197.136.2",
  "user_agent": "Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO",
  "token": "3b6s7984d2d8a97f7e9cg5da14bd6715",
  "token_expiration": "",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "message": "",
  "url": "http://mybackend.com/conectagov/conectagov-prod-imovel-cadastro?token=abc123&cod_imovel=123456",
  "params": {
    "cod_imovel": "123456"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "format": "json",
  "filename": "",
  "limit": 100,
  "offset": 0,
  "result_count": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "imovel_identificador_imovel": 12152583,
      "imovel_codigo_imovel": "123456",
      "imovel_codigo_versao": "1.9.2",
      "imovel_tipo_origem": "EST",
      "imovel_protocolo": "MT-123",
      "imovel_data_ultimo_protocolo": "09/10/2023",
      "imovel_status_imovel": "AT",
      "imovel_tipo_imovel": "IRU",
    }
  ]
}

I want remove a lot of fields:
{
  "result": [
    {
      "imovel_identificador_imovel": 12152583,
      "imovel_codigo_imovel": "123456",
      "imovel_codigo_versao": "1.9.2",
      "imovel_tipo_origem": "EST",
      "imovel_protocolo": "MT-123",
      "imovel_data_ultimo_protocolo": "09/10/2023",
      "imovel_status_imovel": "AT",
      "imovel_tipo_imovel": "IRU",
    }
  ]
}

And I wait to change some field names like "imovel_identificador_imovel" -> "identificadorImovel". So, my JSON would be something like:
{
  "result": [
    {
      "identificadorImovel": 12152583,
      "codigoImovel": "123456",
      "codigoVersao": "1.9.2",
      "tipoOrigem": "EST",
      "protocolo": "MT-123",
      "dataUltimoProtocolo": "09/10/2023",
      "statusImovel": "AT",
      "tipoImovel": "IRU",
    }
  ]
}

Since now, thanks by any help.

You can achieve this by adding an operation policy to the API with Payload Factory mediator. You can process and transform the json content in your payload using this mediator on the response path. Refer the following to get an idea about this.
[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/regular-gateway-policies/transforming-api-message-payload/
[2] - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/json_examples/json-examples/#constructing-and-transforming-json-payloads
